# Center text horizontally and vertically without display table

Tags: css, position

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/j4zvyz7h/1/

I need a overlay the full width and height of the page and text to be dead center.

I can do this with display: table; but I need height: 100%; on the html and body.

This is causing problems in the actual code.

Is it possible to have the 100% overlay with centered text without display: table;

I have an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/j4zvyz7h/2/

I can center it horizontally but not vertically.

Is it possible to center the text horizontally in the second example.

```
        html, body{
            height: 100%;    
        }

        .block{
            background: rgba(230, 97, 97, 0.4);
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .text{
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
.text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4zvyz7h/5/

You would have to adjust the margins a bit to perfectly center it though. A negative margin-top with values exactly half of your element's height will do it.

Answer (score 1):

The 'correct' way of achieving this is using `display: flex;`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/uzkhLjkx/)

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 350px;
}
.box > p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <p>Centered content goes here</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

[**Demo for full screen centered content**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/uzkhLjkx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of absolute positioning and transforms. Here's an example forked from your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/dwkn5563/

```
.text{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: If you want to center it inside an outer div, you need to add `position: relative;` to the outer div.